# How to use filters?

Tags: r, filter

I want to filter my data according to sites, how can I do that for the following code? I am trying to use package dplyr, but I am unable to filter.

```
myData2 <- ggplot(myData,aes(year,bleaching)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = site))+ facet_wrap(~kind) 
myData2
myData3 <- myData2 + geom_smooth(aes(group = 1),
               method = "lm",
               color = "black",
               formula = y~ poly(x, 2),
               se = FALSE)
myData3
library(dplyr)
filter(myData3,site == "site02")
myData3
```

Comment: You are trying to filter a `ggplot` object, not a `data.frame`. Filter `myData` and then plot it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing some things that are bad practice in your example code - namely creating ggplot objects and naming them 'mydata' (it's a plot, not a dataframe).

So let's clean up a bit.

First, we declare the data frame we want to plot

```
mydata_site02 <- filter(myData,site == "site02")
```

Then, we make our plot.

```
ggplot(myData,aes(year,bleaching)) +
geom_point(aes(color = site))+ 
facet_wrap(~kind) + 
geom_smooth(aes(group = 1),
method = "lm",
color = "black",
formula = y~ poly(x, 2),
           se = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.